# Get dates of next 8 Saturdays (javascript)

Tags: javascript, date, dayofweek, getdate

I was able to get date of closest Saturday - [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cIHar)

Need help with finding dates of the next seven saturdays.
Thank you

```
function myFunction(x){
    var now = new Date();  
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + (x+(7-now.getDay())) % 7);
    document.getElementById("1s").innerHTML = now.getDate() + ' of ' + now.getMonth() + 'th';
}
```

Comment: Maybe add 7 to the date once you've found the first saturday to get the second?

Comment: It could give me numbers out of 30-31 day range of each month...

Comment: That does not matter; JavaScript will give you a corrected date object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 7 days to the date you got and loop desired number of weeks ahead.

```
function myFunction(x){

    var now = new Date();  

    now.setDate(now.getDate() + (x+(7-now.getDay())) % 7);
    document.getElementById("1s").innerHTML = now.getDate() + ' of ' + now.getMonth() + 'th';

    var newDate = now;   
    for (var i = 2; i <= 8; i++) {

      var numberOfDaysToAdd = 7;
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 

      document.getElementById("" + i + "s").innerHTML = newDate.getDate() + ' of ' + newDate.getMonth() + 'th';
    }

}
```

**[Forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CbtvA)**